# how to update many rows at same time using my sql

Tags: mysql

I got one table called `family`, which contains a column called `power`. I want to update maximum ten values of power by adding one in each row and the rest remains the same. I try my own method by creating another table which contains the maximum ten values that I want to update and create a query below, but got some problems. Here's the query:

```
UPDATE family
  SET family.total = (SELECT totalmax.total FROM totalmax 
    INNER JOIN  familyone
    ON family.family_id2 = totalmax.family_id2
    WHERE family.family_id2 = totalmax.family_id2)
```

Can someone tell me where's the problem with this query and is there any other methods to solve my problem?

Comment: the subquery will select from table totalmax and familyone, then in your on and where condition you use the table family, is it a typo? Also the on condition and where condition are the same here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a join

```
UPDATE  family
INNER JOIN
        totalmax
ON      family.family_id2 = totalmax.family_id2
SET     family.total = totalmax.total
```